# Android Studio SDK not showing support for Android 7.1.2?

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently got notified from a user running the Xiaomi Remi 4x android 7.1.2 that my app is crashing. However on my Android 8.1.0 Samsung Galaxy Note 9 it is running just fine.

I tried to therefore download the 7.1.2 SDK however I can't even find it on the SDK Manager nor the AVD Manager. Has support for 7.1.2 been rejected or why can't I seem to find it?

I'm also currently running Android Studio 3.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android version 7.1.2 is not a separate platform/API level, it is just version 7.1 plus several functionality and security patches.

See the full list of Android API levels:
https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers

If your app does not work on a Xiaomi device most likely the Android version is not the problem but the adaptions Xiaomi made to Android and/or an incompatibility regarding a certain driver (e.g. graphics).

Therefore most likely even if you could get an Android 7.1.2 platform you won't be able to reproduce the error. Therefore I see three options which may be possible:

1. Check if Xiaomi provides own emulator images for certain devices (not very likely but who knows)
2. Try to get a physical Xiaomi device of the same product branch
3. Use an online service that provides you remote access to a physical Xiaomi device for installing your app and debugging it. Such services are also known as "device farm"
4. Ask the affected user to provide StackTraces and then try to understand what is going wrong (and of course StackOverflow for the problem), provide test releases to the user. Redo this loop until the problem has been solved.

Comment: I'll also add this.  Does your app rely on any Google Play Services features (Fused Location Provider API, Google Maps, Google Sign In, etc) and does the Xiaomi phone have Google Play Services installed. (i.e. Is the Google Play store installed on the phone?) . If your app relies on Google Play Services and if it's not installed, then that could be the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I will try out these options. I appreciate the quick response.